# Why Is this HTML String so Redundant?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple newsletter, and I'm wondering why this code I found is so redundant.

```
<td id="m_1257726376905495529templateFooter" style="background:#0066cc none no-
repeat center/cover;background-color:#0066cc;background-image:none;background-
repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size:cover;border-
top:0;border-bottom:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px" valign="top">
```

Why is the code above so redundant?

Comment: What do you mean by redundant exactly? It's also hard to answer a question about asking for the intent of the html. It's more helpful if you ask about a specific part of the html that is confusing or not working properly.

Comment: It looks this complex because the person who wrote it wanted it styled in a very specific way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the low level of CSS support by most e-mail clients. The use of CSS classes, selectors etc. is often not supported. That's why it is considered as best practice to inline all the CSS styles within the HTML document and to avoid compound style declarations like `background: #0066CC none no-repeat center/cover`.

Another reason may be that compound style declarations are easier to read by humans, but the content may not be rendered correctly. Thus, simple `background-*` styles are also applied, for compatibility purposes.

Of course, these are not all possible reasons.

I recommend getting acquainted with some [guidelines in e-mail newsletter design](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/), even if you're creating a very basic one.

[Here is a table with major e-mail clients support of CSS.](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)

Comment: Thanks.  This is helping me understand the code, so it's not as confusing as before.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer @FIL gave, this might be due to email client support. Some do not support the background shorthand property, so all of the regular background-* properties were added. Is it possible that this inline style wasn't written by hand but was added by some build step.  That might explain why there is duplication which is what I believe is the redundancy you are referring to.

Comment: but in all the cases the shorthand will be overriden by the other, so this is a bit *strange* as code .. I would write only the longhand ones

Comment: I agree, I would write only the longhand, but maybe there is some build tool that allows you to write the short hand, and it auto expands into long hand, but doesn't do the clean up of deleting the shorthand.  Just offering a possibility.